# Can't retrieve the device token

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I implemented these lines of code in the client app into the appDelegate.m file :

```
    NSLog(@"Registering for push notification..");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didregisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSString *myDeviceToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
NSLog(@"device Token =%@", myDeviceToken);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
{
//NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error; %@", err];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
for (id key in userInfo) {
    NSLog(@"key:%@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
}
}
```

But didregisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken never gets called neither does didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError. I can find my app under settings>Notification on my device but cant retrieve the device token. Also under Xcode>Organizer>MyiPhone>Console there are those errors :

> Error: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
>
> Error: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
>
> Error: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning.

would you guys have any idea what the problem could be ?
Many thank

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your entitlements file doesn't match what's in your provisioning profile. Try opening your provisioning profile with a text editor, you'll see a lot of garbage but you'll see what's listed for entitlements. Make sure you set your entitlements file to match what's in your provisioning profile exactly.

Comment: I added an entitlements file according to my provisioning profile but still no device token !

Comment: I am still getting this error ! I don't know if that could help but I have one profile file for the push notification and more than one provisioning profile file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . It will definitely helps

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString* deviceTokenStr = [deviceToken description];
    deviceTokenStr = [deviceTokenStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceTokenStr = [deviceTokenStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"Device token ===> %@",deviceTokenStr);

    NSString* myDeviceToken=deviceTokenStr;

    NSLog(@"device Token =%@", myDeviceToken);
}
```

Create a new provisioning profile and enable push notification service.

**Note :**  Your bundle identifier should be without wildcard character.

Please let me know if u still face any problem.